# Changing button name if file exists?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a custom GUI, my last step is for the button to change automatically check if the file exists or not on startup. The method below is my download/open button. Any help is appreciated!

> ```
> Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
>     If Dir("DownloadedFile.zip") <> "" Then
>         Process.Start("DownloadedFile.zip")
>     Else
>         WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://download852.mediafire.com/3a688rz1a6ig/dk71cs34ihs3v6x/Devil+went+down+to+georgia.rar"), "DownloadedFile.zip")
>         MsgBox("Starting Download")
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: take your logic and put it in a subroutine, that way it can be called from your click event and called also in your constructor, load or shown events

Comment: Not sure what a subroutine is, can you tell me some info or show me?
sorry in advance

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

A subroutine is a seperate method that does not return a value. I would take the If statement out of your click eventhandler and put it in its own method as I stated like this.

```
Private Sub CheckForFile()
    If Dir("DownloadedFile.zip") <> "" Then
        Process.Start("DownloadedFile.zip")
    Else
        WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://download852.mediafire.com/3a688rz1a6ig/dk71cs34ihs3v6x/Devil+went+down+to+georgia.rar"), "DownloadedFile.zip")
        MsgBox("Starting Download")
    End If
End Sub
```

Call it from your button like this.

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    CheckForFile()
End Sub
```

Then handle the Shown Event and call it from there. It will run as soon as the initial form is shown

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    CheckForFile()
End Sub
```

---

Responding to your comment You need to use the WebClient [DownloadFileCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Event and the WebClient [DownloadProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Event

Comment: Thanks, I needed to figure out what was the 'main method' so to speak of visual basic, now it works upon startup. Was also now wondering how to make it like: if (progressbar1.value = 100) then (etc..) but didn't seem to work to update automatically when u click the download button and starts. (overall, I want the button to automatically update if progress is 100% done)